# Date decrement and parse on array

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array with different dates:

- 2017-10-25
- 2017-11-17
  etc.

From given parameters, I have calculated a date: `$MEDIA_NDATE`.

If it doesn't match with any date in the array I would want the function to decrement `$MEDIA_NDATE` until it matches with a date in the array.

I tried different things but I didn't find the right one :(

```
function contains() {
i=0
len=${#arr[@]}


     while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
        for j in "${arr[@]}"
          do
           if [ "$j" == "$MEDIA_NDATE" ];then
                echo " value of media_ndate --> : $MEDIA_NDATE"
                  return 0

            elif [ "$j" != "$MEDIA_NDATE" ];then
                      let i++ 

            elif [ "$i" -eq "$len" ] && [ "$j" != "$MEDIA_NDATE"];then
 #                     MEDIA_NDATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d  "$MEDIA_NDATE -i day") 
 #                      echo "value of media_ndate in function contains $MEDIA_NDATE "
           fi
        done
     done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can achieve this by searching for the exact date in one loop while keeping track of all the dates prior to `$MEDIA_NDATE` by adding them to a temporary array `dates`. If there is an exact match, you return from the function and if there isn't, you search the array `dates` for a date closest to `$MEDIA_NDATE`.

For easier handling, such as dates comparison, it is useful to convert all the dates into a portable format with `date -d "$some_date" +%s` and convert it back to the desired format at the end of the function.

```
contains() {
   local -a dates
   local media_date=$(date -d "$MEDIA_NDATE" +%s)
   local currDate
   local j

   for j in "${arr[@]}"; do
      if [ "$j" == "$MEDIA_NDATE" ]; then
         echo "Value of media_ndate --> $MEDIA_NDATE"
         return 0
      fi

      currDate=$(date -d "$j" +%s)
      (( currDate < media_date )) && dates+=($currDate)

   done

   [[ ${#dates[@]} -eq 0 ]] && return 1
   local result=$(printf -- '%s\n' "${dates[@]}" | sort -nr | head -n 1)

   MEDIA_NDATE=$(date -d "@$result" '+%Y-%m-%d')
   echo "Value of media_ndate --> $MEDIA_NDATE"
   return 0 
}
```

**EDIT:** I added a better solution that doesn't need a temporary array and only keeps track of the closest date:

```
contains() {
   [[ ${#arr[@]} -le 0 ]] && return 1

   local media_date=$(date -d "$MEDIA_NDATE" +%s)
   local max_date=$(date -d "${arr[0]}" +%s)
   local curr_date
   local j

   for j in "${arr[@]}"; do
      if [ "$j" == "$MEDIA_NDATE" ]; then
         echo "Value of media_ndate --> $MEDIA_NDATE"
         return 0
      fi

      curr_date=$(date -d "$j" +%s)
      (( curr_date < media_date && curr_date > max_date )) && max_date=$curr_date

   done

   (( max_date > media_date )) && return 1

   MEDIA_NDATE=$(date -d "@$max_date" '+%Y-%m-%d')
   echo "Value of media_ndate --> $MEDIA_NDATE"
}
```

Comment: @john_doe if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.